# Sumar columnas de una tabla con javascript sin concatenar

Tags: javascript, datatables

Estoy haciendo una funcion donde voy cargando cuotas en una tabla.
Luego en la misma puedo editar descuento y recarga. esto calcula un subtotal. y luego el total.
me anda todo perfecto menos cuando quiero sumar el recargo. es decir cuando resto el descuento lo hace bien, pero cuando quiero sumar el recargo me lo concatenar en lugar de sumar.
Ya probe con parsefloat pero tampoco funcion. Dejo el codigo por si sirve de referencia.

```
function agregarDetalle(idcategoria,nombre,valor_cuota){
    var descuento=0;
    var recargo=0;
    var subtotal =0;


    if (idcategoria!="") {
        var subtotal= valor_cuota;
        var fila='<tr class="filas" id="fila'+cont+'">'+
        '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarDetalle('+cont+')">X</button></td>'+
        '<td><input type="text"   style="width:80px;"  name="idpersona" value="" readonly></td>'+
        '<td><input type="number" style="width:80px;" name="valor_cuota[]" id="valor_cuota[]" value="'+valor_cuota+'" readonly></td>'+
        '<td><input type="number" style="width:80px;" name="anio[]" id="anio[]" value=""></td>'+
        '<td><input type="number" style="width:80px;" name="mes[]" id="mes[]" value=""></td>'+
        '<td><input type="number" style="width:80px;" name="descuento[]" value="'+descuento+'"></td>'+
        '<td><input type="number" style="width:80px;" name="recargo[]" value="'+recargo+'"></td>'+
        '<td><span id="subtotal'+cont+'" name="subtotal">'+subtotal+'</span></td>'+
        '<td><button type="button" onclick="modificarSubtotales()" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button></td>'+
        '</tr>';
        cont++;
        detalles++;
        $('#detalles').append(fila);
        modificarSubtotales();

    }else{
        alert("error al ingresar la cuota, revisar las datos cargados");
    }
}
function modificarSubtotales(){

    var vc=document.getElementsByName("valor_cuota[]");
    var desc=document.getElementsByName("descuento[]");
    var rec=document.getElementsByName("recargo[]");
    var sub=document.getElementsByName("subtotal");

    for (var i = 0; i < cont; i++) {
        var inpP=vc[i];
        var inpS=sub[i];
        var des=desc[i];
        var rec=rec[i];


        inpS.value=inpP.value-des.value +rec.value ;
        document.getElementsByName("subtotal")[i].innerHTML=inpS.value;
    }

    calcularTotales();
}
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a esta línea: `inpS.value=inpP.value-des.value +rec.value`? Deberías hacer `parse` de todos los valores que ahí intervienen.

Comment: si,probe con parse pero no me lo resolvio

Comment: Yo no logró entender del todo tu código, ¿qué hay realmente en `inpP.value`, en `des.value` y en `rec.value`?  ¿Verificaste esos valores con `console.log`?

Comment: si los valores los toma bien, como estan en la tabla

Comment: Intenta forzar los valores a `0` por  si acaso alguno no es numérico, porque eso rompería la operación posterior. Para no hacer demasiado lío, puedes recuperar el dato del `value` en las variables con algo así: `var inpP=parseFloat(vc[i].value)  || 0; var des=parseFloat(desc[i].value) || 0; var rec=parseFloat(rec[i].value)  || 0;` y luego en la operación ya no usas `value`, sino las variables: `inpS.value=inpP-des+rec ;`

Comment: no. me pasa lo mismo, primer fila bien la segunda ya tira error

Comment: ¿De dónde tomas el valor de `cont` que usarías para saber cuantos elementos hay? Yo por más que analizo tu código no lo entiendo, creo que convendría replanteamiento del mismo en la lógica que estás siguiendo.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo estas teniendo un problema de tipos (que suele pasar en los lenguajes con tipado dinámico).

Lo que debes hacer es antes de hacer la suma garantizar que todas las variables involucradas sean números (int, float, etc). Caso contrario al hacer la suma de un numero con un string por ejemplo, la suma no va a hacer lo que esperas y va a concatenar el string con el numero.

Por ejemplo:

```
"1" + 1 = "11"
```

Para esto podes usar: parseInt, parseFloat, multiplicar * 1 a la variable (no es muy intuitivo pero funciona)

En el caso de la resta, aunque los valores sean strings se aplica la resta aritmetica, por eso `inpP.value-des.value` te está andado bien.

Pero luego al resultado le está sumando un string y NUMERO + STRING => Aplica la concatenación. (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Aritm%C3%A9ticos)

Espero haberte ayudado!

Answer (score 0):

Ahi probe con los parseInt. me funciona perfecto cuando agregas una fila, pero cuando agregas la segunda tira un error de indefinido el rec.value tanto cuando calculo el subtotal, como los totales.. en todos los casos igual.si cargo uno solo, perfecto si agrego mas error. no se porque..

```
function modificarSubtotales(){

    var vc=document.getElementsByName("valor_cuota[]");
    var desc=document.getElementsByName("descuento[]");
    var rec=document.getElementsByName("recargo[]");
    var sub=document.getElementsByName("subtotal");

    for (var i = 0; i < cont; i++) {
        var inpP=vc[i];
        var inpS=sub[i];
        var des=desc[i];
        var rec=rec[i];
        


        inpS.value= parseInt(inpP.value) + parseInt(rec.value) - parseInt(des.value)  ;
        document.getElementsByName("subtotal")[i].innerHTML=inpS.value;
    }

    calcularTotales();
}

function calcularTotales(){
    var sub = document.getElementsByName("subtotal");
    var total=0.0;

    for (var i = 0; i < sub.length; i++) {
        total += document.getElementsByName("subtotal")[i].value;
    }
    $("#total").html("S/." + total);
    $("#total_pagado").val(total);
    evaluar();
}
```